# Deleting m nodes in Singly Linked Lists

Tags: c++, linked-list

Write the code for the function `bool DeleteMNodes (int x, int m)`.
The function deletes the first `m` nodes with value `x`. If there is at least one node with value `x`, it returns true; otherwise, it returns false. If the number of nodes with value `x` is less than `m`, it deletes all the nodes with value `x`. The function should run in `O(n)`.

Here is the class of the SSL nodes:

```
class IntSLLNode
{
public:
    int val;
    IntSLLNode* next;

    IntSLLNode(int val,IntSLLNode* next);
    ~IntSLLNode();
};
```

And this is the SSL class:

```
class IntSLList
{
public:
    IntSLList();
    ~IntSLList();

    bool IsEmpty(void);
    void AddToHead(int val);
    void AddToTail(int val);
    void DeleteFromHead(void);
    void DeleteFromTail(void);
    bool DeleteNode(int val);
    bool IsInList(int val);
    bool DeleteMNodes (int x, int m); //My function
    void Print();

private:
    IntSLLNode *head, *tail;
};
```

Here is my implementation of `DeleteMNodes(int x, int m)` function:

```
bool IntSLList::DeleteMNodes(int x, int m)
{
    IntSLLNode *pred, *tmp, *delNode;
    int count=0;
    if (IsEmpty())
        return false;

    if (count <= m) {
        if (head->val == x) {
            DeleteFromHead();
            count++;
        }
    }

    for (pred=head, tmp=head->next; tmp!=NULL;)
    {    
        if (count <= m)
        {
            if (tmp->val == x)
            {
                delNode = tmp;
                pred->next = tmp->next;
                tmp = tmp->next;
                delete delNode;
                count++;
            }
            else {
                pred = pred->next;
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }

        }
    }
    if (count>=1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it is not working!. What is the wrong?

Comment: What's the errors you got ?

Comment: I think that it enters an infinite loop. When I change `count <= m` to `count < m` it runs but give wrong results (i.e deletes more than m nodes)

Comment: I need to see when you're calling `DeleteMNodes`. Also, notice that your counter is initialize to 0, thus if you want `m` nodes to be deleted, it should be `count < m`.

Comment: Please don't use tags without checking what they're for. The SSL tag is for questions about the Secure Sockets Layer. 'SSL' is not a standard abbreviation for 'singly linked list'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not advancing the pointers after count reach m. You have several options like this one for example:

```
for (pred=head, tmp=head->next; tmp!=NULL;)
{    
    bool didDelete = false;
    if (count <= m)
    {
        if (tmp->val == x)
        {
            delNode = tmp;
            pred->next = tmp->next;
            tmp = tmp->next;
            delete delNode;
            count++;
            didDelete = true;
        }
    }

    if(!didDelete) 
    {
        pred = pred->next;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

Or you could just break the for once m == count.

```
for (pred=head, tmp=head->next; tmp!=NULL;)
{    
    if (count <= m)
    {
        if (tmp->val == x)
        {
            delNode = tmp;
            pred->next = tmp->next;
            tmp = tmp->next;
            delete delNode;
            count++;
        }
        else {
            pred = pred->next;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

I would probably prefer the last one since avoid unnecessary iterations.